# Sql Server Agent job stopping at 11PM?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

We have a SQL Server Agent Job that needs to run hourly without end. And I believe it's configured that way. Unfortunately, this time it stopped running at 11pm.

Here's the screenshot of the history and the job schedule. The history shows that it ran hourly successfully until 11pm on 12/11.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Well it did run until the time specified. You cut it off before the clock hit midnight.

Comment: The next hour after 11 is **12** as it only runs till 11:59:59 **11** is the last hour it runs in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your schedule is configured to only run between 7pm and 11:59:59pm, so the job will run at 11pm, but when midnight rolls around, it is after 11:59:59pm, so then it will not run again until 7pm the following day.